# exec() using different php version

Tags: php, exec, command-line-interface

I'm using Mac OS X (10.11.6) with MAMP PRO 3 and PHP 5.6.10. I've setup the PATH in .bash_profile and everything looks fine. 
When I do `which php` in the terminal I get the following correct path:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php
```

Now I'm trying to execute an exec-command with PHP along the lines of the following example:

```
exec('which php');
```

This returns `/usr/bin/php` and therefore is wrong, I want it to use the other version too.

My MAMP related things from .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:$PATH
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running exec('which php') via a browser request to a web server running on your local machine?  If yes, maybe that web server runs under a different id and so doesn't run your user id's .bash_profile when it starts up.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder the exec is coming from a php application on mamp accessed through the browser. I understand what you mean, so where would I have to set the version? With an alias somewhere?

Comment: There's probably several answers.  For something like this, I'd probably put it with the rest of my applications environmental configuration (wherever you might have that).  The less places you have config, the less likely something will be missed, and the less fragile your app will be as its deployed in different environs.  So, instead of `exec('php mycmd.php')` and hoping PATH is set up correctly, do `exec($pathToPHPfromConfig . ' mycmd.php')`;